# Wondering if any application server available for Android platform

Tags: java, application-server

We have several web applications we'd like to bring close to mobile customers, e.g. allowing run them directly on mobile platform like Android.

Answer (score 1):

There are several application servers available for mobile platforms, say more applications server extends capabilities of mobile platform greatly. So currently two major vendors compete in this market Jetty and TJWS with corresponding products as **i-Jetty** and **Atjeews**. Check them out and start building web applications for mobile platforms today.